# Android Studio Installation of Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to install Android Studio, and the process of installing Android SDK takes ages.
This is because of the download of the zipped components. For example, the download of
**https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-31_r01.zip** took about 20 minutes.

I noticed that when I'm downloading the components directly using the browser they get downloaded quickly enough, and the download in Android Studio takes significantly longer. Why is it so? Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Comment: For whomever is voting to close this as general computing, please [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  Questions about using software are only off-topic if they do not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the latest version of Android studio (2020.3.1) for windows has a total file size of 914 MB whereas the Zip file you are downloading is only 53 MB in size. This is a little because it is zip but this is not the only reason. This also not contain all the required files and will download during installation.

I suggest to download it from android studio site only as you will get latest package.